# ReactJS: use onClick and state to display a subset of elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I've just started learning React and have a question

I have a list of items, based on its type, I want to display a portion of it when click a button. Sort of like “first page”, “prev”, “next”, “last page” kind of thing, instead, it would be “type A”, “type B”, etc. So when a user clicks on "type A", the list of items that has the prooperty of type A will be displayed.

This is what I‘ve got … will this work? I’m a bit fuzzy on how to write the separateQuestsByType() function, what should be returned? and how will this work if at all.

```
class QuestList extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.state = {page:quests};
    }

render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <p className="bg-info" >Here is the list of requests
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <div className="btn-group">
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({page:quests})} >Quests</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({page:collections})} >Collections</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({page:specialquests})} >Special Quests</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({page:others})} >Others</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th className="col-md-2">Name</th>
                            <th className="col-md-2">ID</th>
                            <th className="col-md-2">Description</th>
                            <th className="col-md-2">Created Time (Pacific Time)</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.requests.filter(separateQuestsByType).map(this.renderRequestRow.bind(this))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.props.onAdd}>Add NewRequest</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

separateQuestsByType(){

}
    renderRequestRow(campaign, i) {
        return (
            <tr key={i}>
                <td>{quest.name}</td>
                <td>{quest.id}</td>
                <td>{quest.description}</td>
                <td>{quest.createdTime}</td>
            </tr>
        );
    }
```

Version 2, I updated the previous code to the following:

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {};
        this.state = {type:typeA};
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="row">
                        <div className="col">
                            <div className="btn-group">
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:typeA})} >Quests</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:typeB})} >Collections</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:typeD})} >Special Quests</button>
                                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={()=>this.setState({type:others})} >Others</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <table className="table table-striped">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
...
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.campaigns.filter(this.separateQuestsByType.bind(this)).map(this.renderQuestRow.bind(this))}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.props.onAdd}>Add New Request</button>
            </div>
        );
    }

    separateQuestsByType(quest) {
        return quest.type === this.state.type
    }
```

It all works fine, except the last one, I want to make it a catch-all category ... is there a way that I can make state.type as if it is not anything above?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your `state.page` is what you're using to filter?  Assuming each `request` item has a prop that corresponds to the possible values of `state.page`, your `separateQuestsByType` would be a simple filter:

```js
separateQuestsByType(request){
  return request.someProp === this.state.page
}
```

Or you can do it inline:

```js
{this.props.requests
   .filter(request => request.someProp === this.state.page)
   .map(this.renderRequestRow.bind(this))
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I updated the code (see the above, version 2) and it works for the most part. Furthermore, is there a way to make the last one as a catch-all category? I mean clicking the last button "Others" to display all the other types of quests. Is there a way to specify state.type not equal to something?

Comment: You can set a `default` in a switch statement.  Check it out [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch).  Also, if this answer helped you, please upvote. I love me some meaningless internet points.